# FreeOPCUA python client example

Tags: python, linux, opc-ua

I am using [freeOpcua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua) to write a simple client example. I first tested this in my laptop by running its server code and then running client code from linux in raspberry pi3. So I was able to connect to server .

Now I have a PLC which is running B&R Server. I need to connect to this server and get the attributes value but I everytime I try to connect it shows `connection refused error`. The server is running fine because I have tested it using client software on windows but not connecting in linux. I am using freeopcua client example to connect to server.

**Do I need to enable port on which I am trying to communicate.?**

Does anyone have any experience in this. Please help. Thanks.

EDIT:

The IP address is 192.168.1.21 and the port number is 135. I am doing something like below:

```
client = Client("opc.tcp://192.168.1.21:135/")
client.connect()
#This gives error of connection refused.
```

I opened the client.connect() and found out that it has below functions:

```
connect_socket()
send_hello()
open_secure_channel()
create_session()
activate_session()
```

So instead of doing `client.connect()` I did `client.connect_socket()` So it went ok and didnt gave any error. Then I `print(client.get_root_node())` it showed me `Node(TwoByteNodeId(i=84))` and `print(client.get_server_node())` it shows `Node(FourByteNodeId(i=2253))`. What are these values. Can I consider that I am able to connect to the server by doing `client.connect_socket()`.

When I tried to get the endpoints by using `client.get_endpoints()` it gave me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "opcua/client/client.py", line 299, in get_endpoints
    return self.uaclient.get_endpoints(params)
  File "opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 323, in get_endpoints
    data = self._uasocket.send_request(request)
  File "opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 76, in send_request
    data = future.result(self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", 
line 431, in result
    raise TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

Also when I tried to do `open_secure_channel()` or `create_session()` or any other it gave me above error.

Comment: Is there any more error information available? Can you display the endpoints returned by the server?

Comment: @KevinHerron Please have a look at the edit

Comment: Those get node methods don't require that you're connected, they just build NodeIds. You've got the wrong IP/port or the server isn't running or allowing connections. Connection refused is connection refused.

Comment: But then whats client.connect_socket() doing.  Isn't it making a connection to the client.?

Comment: Don't know, look at the library code. Maybe it just sets the socket up but it's not actually used until you try to send a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem. I found out that the Hello message was setting the `MaxMessageSize` and `MaxChunkCount` to 0. I changed the `freeopcua` code so that it set to the same values used by `UaExpert`, and it worked.

So in the `freeopcua` code, in `freeopcua/ua/uaprotocol_hand.py`, I changed the **init** of the Hello class:

```
class Hello(uatypes.FrozenClass):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ProtocolVersion = 0
        self.ReceiveBufferSize = 65536
        self.SendBufferSize = 65536
        self.MaxMessageSize = 16777216
        self.MaxChunkCount = 5000
        self.EndpointUrl = ""
        self._freeze = True
```

If you don't know how to edit a python package, mine was located here: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\opcua\ua`

Basically your `python_directory\Lib\site-packages\opcua\ua`

Edit: My open_secure_channel() was working before I made this change, so you may have a different problem. Before this change my create_sessions() and get_endpoints() would always fail.

Comment: Great. Thanks. You used uaexpert from linux or windows. Which version of windows 10,8,7?

Comment: I am using windows 7